# How can I test CallBack Api (social network Vk) using localhost?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, vk

I want to write a chat bot in vk. I wrote a rest api and several methods for bot communication. But how do I test what I have done before publishing to the server?

Comment: Use mocks: abstract out outter world.

Comment: Are you want to test api methods? please add more details

Comment: as already mentioned by Sereja Bogolubov, use mocks to abstract the outter world. this way you can easily unit test your API in an automated way. if you want to see the requests of your API and send back some test data manually, PostMan (https://www.getpostman.com/) may be something you want to take a look at. PostMan is an API development environment and there is also a free demo which I found very helpful.

Comment: @Pete, I wanted to get maybe debug specific methods online. That is, get data from VkApi and watch how my method works in the controller. I tried to use ngrok (ngrok.com). Ngrok exposes local servers behind NATs and firewalls to the public internet over secure tunnels. But this did not give a positive result. Perhaps you can do without Mocks? I am new to this business, so I apologize in advance if my ideas are obsessive